# OAuth 2.0 auth code grant flow vs client credential grant flow

Tags: .net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

We have a 3rd party mobile app. Which during the login process creates an access token to access one of our API(.netcore) using the Authorization code grant flow.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code

[image]

[image]

The mobile app displays many tiles. After login, when the user clicks on one of the tiles, I want to call another .netcore API(using the access_token).

I was planning to use client credential flow for the second API call as it does not require user interaction.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

[image]

But the API endpoint(in the code) checks the Claims to get the userID and client credential flow creates a jwt token without the user information(as there is no user interaction).

Am I using the correct flow? Is there a way to use authorization code grant flow when clicking the tile(without needing a user interaction)?

Answer (score 1):

You can only get the user information when use auth code flow which need a user interaction.

I noticed that you are using v1.0 endpoint, you can put the api uri in the resource parameter. Scope parameter isn't needed for v1.0 endpoint. You can get the access token silently after logging in.

Here is the code snippet for your reference.

```
 // Because we signed-in already in the WebApp, the userObjectId is know
                string userObjectID = (User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"))?.Value;

                // Using ADAL.Net, get a bearer token to access the TodoListService
                AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(AzureAdOptions.Settings.Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID, HttpContext.Session));
                ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(AzureAdOptions.Settings.ClientId, AzureAdOptions.Settings.ClientSecret);
                result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(AzureAdOptions.Settings.TodoListResourceId, credential, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

                // Retrieve the user's To Do List.
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, AzureAdOptions.Settings.TodoListBaseAddress + "/api/todolist");
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Reference:

[active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/tree/master/TodoListWebApp)

Comment: Also as a note, a mobile app should never use client credentials flow, unless it is from its back-end service. Client credentials requires the use of a secret/certificate, which should never be used in a public client application such as a mobile app.

Comment: @juunas, The app has a server side code section as well. So I was planning to write an Azure Function which uses Client credential flow(ADAL.NET) to create the access token(host the Azure function in our azure platform). The mobile apps server code will then access the Azure fuction to get the access_token. Then it will pass it in the header of the API call from the apps serverside.Is it ok to use client credential in this scenario?

Comment: Thanks Tony, I will have a look into the code and let you know.

Comment: Right, the back-end function can definitely call the API using client credentials. If you'd like to call the API as the user and you have an access token with user info, you can also use the on-behalf-of grant to get a new token with user info for the API you want to call

Comment: @juunas, The flow diagram in the below link shows the user need to be authenticated first in the app. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow. Also I do not have a down stream API(Web API B in the flow diagram). So how can I use ob behalf of? Do you know any code samples?

Comment: Right, so for on-behalf-of you need to have the user authenticate at the client application. If you don't want that, then your only option is client credentials in the back-end. I do have a sample link: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapi-onbehalfof

Comment: @juunas Is it possible/correct to use authorisation code grant flow + openid, when clicking the app tile? Will that ask the user to re login? As far as I understand Auth code grant flow is used with users consent, so probably at the login, is that right?

Comment: @NewBieDevRo Yes, user interaction will be needed when use code grant flow. User consent will popup when the user login at the first time.

Comment: @NewBieDevRo Just let me know if you have any other concerns, if not, can you make it as answer? Thank you.